# createsuperuser in Django-pycharm

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, pycharm

when press ctrl+alt+r ("Enter Manage.py task name") and enter to createsuperuser, it ask me for-email, password and username. and when I enter it print-"Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  ImportError: cannot import name 'setup_environ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of python and django?

It looks like it was a bug fixed in http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-2221

Answer (score 0):

Goto : PyCharm > Tools > Run django Console >

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.create_superuser(username='yourUsername', password='YourPassword', email='your@email.PK')
```

Cheers !